# no errors but the button linked with intent is not responding in android studios

Tags: android

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        if(name.equals("xyz") && password.equals("xyz")) {                              
            Intent intLogin = new Intent(LoginPage.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            intLogin.putExtra("id", value);
            startActivity(intLogin);
        }
    }
});
```

when i am applying this code i dont have any errors but when i click on Login button it is not going to next activity why is it so happening,what to do?

Comment: Are your txtName and txtPassword having "xyz" values.

Comment: do not forget to add SignUpActivity to the manifest.

Comment: @karimkhan it is fine about manifest

Comment: @karimkhan  if i remove if condition then it is working in proper way

Comment: debug your code to see if it is going inside on click listener.

Comment: @mvs So what does that mean?it means that either your txtPassword or txtName don't have "xyz" values.